# ResourceRegistrationFailureException when calling the RegisterThing operation - thing groups conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am getting the following error when trying to use the RegisterThings action from AWS IoT. Within the API, call, I am trying to set the thing groups but getting the following error:

> An error occurred (ResourceRegistrationFailureException) when calling the RegisterThing operation: Existing ThingGroups: [] conflict with ThingGroups: [mythingggroup] in Template

Here is my provisioning template:

```
provision_json = json.dumps({
    "Parameters": {
        "ThingName": {
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "ThingGroup": {
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "CertificateId": {
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "PolicyName": {
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "AssumeRolePolicyName": {
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Thing": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing",
            "Properties": {
                "ThingName": {
                    "Ref": "ThingName"
                },
                "ThingGroups": [{
                    "Ref": "ThingGroup"
                }]
            },
            "OverrideSettings" : {
                "ThingGroups" : "REPLACE"
            }
        },
        "Certificate": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
            "Properties": {
                "CertificateId": {
                    "Ref": "CertificateId"
                }
            }
        },
        "DevicePolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": {
                    "Ref": "PolicyName"
                }
            }
        },
        "TESAssumeRolePolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": {
                    "Ref": "AssumeRolePolicyName"
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

then I call the boto3 client like this:

```
iot = boto3.client("iot")

    response = iot.register_thing(
        templateBody=provision_json,
        parameters={
            "CertificateId": "1234",
            "ThingName": "mythingname",
            "ThingGroup": "mythinggroupname",
            "PolicyName": "mypolicyname",
            "AssumeRolePolicyName": "anotherpolicyname"
        }
    )
```

I thought this might be a permissions error, but even after I give the caller iot:*, I still have the same issue.

AWS isn't providing great documentation on why this error is occurring. Does anyone have any ideas?